# $\mathbb E[ |X| ] < \infty \iff \forall \epsilon : \mathbb E[ |X / \epsilon | ] < \infty$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

$X$ is a random variable.

$$ \mathbb E ( | X | ) < \infty \implies \forall \epsilon > 0, \sum_n \mathbb P ( | X | \geq n \epsilon ) < \infty. $$

Any help to prove this?

(This amounts to prove that $\mathbb E[ |X| ] < \infty \iff  \forall \epsilon :  \mathbb E[ |X / \epsilon | ] < \infty$).

**---------------------------------------------------- original post**

Since I know that  $$X \in L^1 \iff \sum \mathbb P ( | X | \geq n) < \infty$$ I was given the hint to try to prove the statement hereinafter:

Let us say that $X$ is a random variable.

$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists K>0, \forall n \in \mathbb N: \mathbb P( X \geq n \epsilon ) \leq K \mathbb P ( X \geq n), $$

is a useful fact that I need in some proof of my probability lecture, however I am quite unsure about how to prove such statement. Any idea?

**---------------------------------------------------- comment**

I guess that the original post is completly wrong because one cannot bound each term (cf. Ian comment), however bounding the whole sum is doable somehow.

Comment: @Ian please see the editted question, which is the exact statement I need.

Comment: If you assume that $X$ also has finite variance then you can use Chebyshev's inequality. Maybe you can't do any better than this, since if X saturated Markov's inequality then you get the Harmonic Series.

Comment: @user27182 the thing is, we are trying to prove (see edited post) that $X\in L^1$. If you know it is in $L^2$ it becomes trivial... however I can ensure that it has to be true for the sake of my lecturer... the bound seemed easy to him!

Comment: @ Marine, by markov's ineq. it would suffice if the $1+\delta$ order moment is bounded for some $\delta>0$ arbitrarily small; but not sure if we can appeal to that assumption...

Comment: $\mathsf{E}|X|<\infty \Leftrightarrow \mathsf{E}|X/\epsilon|<\infty \Leftrightarrow \sum_{n}\mathsf{P}(|X/\epsilon|\ge  n)<\infty$.

Comment: $X$ is in $L^1$ if and only if $X/\epsilon$ is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}$Recall that $\mathbb E|X|=\int_0^\infty\mathbb P(|X|>t)\dd t$. Then since $t\mapsto\mathbb P(|X|>t)$ is a decreasing function, we can bound this integral via upper and lower Riemann sums as
$$\epsilon\cdot\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb P(|X|>n\epsilon)\leq\int_0^\infty\mathbb P(|X|>t)\dd t\leq\epsilon\cdot\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathbb P(|X|>n\epsilon).$$
So it turns out that $\mathbb E|X|<\infty\iff\sum\mathbb P(|X|>n\epsilon)<\infty$.

Comment: There is a minor error here: both sums should have a $\epsilon$ in front. But yes, this was the idea I was writing up; the desired quantity is a constant times a left hand Riemann sum, the left hand Riemann sum is actually a little bigger than the integral, but it is also just the right hand Riemann sum plus something in $[0,1]$, so the finiteness behavior is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Using the monotone convergence theorem, for any $\epsilon>0$,
$$
\mathsf{E}|X|=\lim_{M\to\infty}\mathsf{E}[|X|\wedge M]=\epsilon\lim_{M\to\infty}\mathsf{E}[|X/\epsilon|\wedge M/\epsilon]=\epsilon\,\mathsf{E}|X/\epsilon|.
$$
Thus,
$$
\mathsf{E}|X|<\infty \Leftrightarrow \mathsf{E}|X/\epsilon|<\infty \Leftrightarrow \sum_{n}\mathsf{P}(|X/\epsilon|\ge  n)<\infty.
$$

Comment: nice idea! I think the M is missing a scaling by epsilon but it is a very concise way to present things. Thanks.

Comment: @MarineGalantin You're right (but it doesn't really matter because of the limit). BTW, typically $\mathsf{E} cX=c\mathsf{E}X$ is proved for $X\in L^1$. However, it holds whenever $\mathsf{E}X$ exists (possibly infinite).